# What is 'execute:' on the command line, and how to I avoid it?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, iterm2

So I am using iTerm 2 on mac OSX, running zsh in case any of this is relevant.

I must have clicked something by accident, because this dialog appeared, and I can't seem to dismiss it:

[image]

Everything that I type shows up next to `execute:`. I have never seen this before and had to `^C` to get out of it.

Anyone know what it is/what I clicked to make it appear?

Comment: Does it show up every time or only once? Are you using d'oh-my-zsh or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"execute: " is the prompt of the `execute-named-cmd` *zle* (*zsh line editor*) widget, which allows you to run any other *zle* widget by entering its name (it even has Tab-completion).

By default is is bound to `ESC-x` (that is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>) in *emacs* mode and to <kbd>:</kbd> in *vicmd* mode (usually reached by typing <kbd>Esc</kbd> from *viins* mode or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> from *emacs* mode).

To remove both default bindings, run

```
bindkey -e -r '^[x'
bindkey -a -r ':'
```

The first one is for *emacs* mode the second one for *vicmd*.

To make it permanent you can put it into your `~/.zshrc`. If there is any call to just `bindkey -e` or `bindkey -v` (without any further arguments the set the default bindings for *emacs* and *viins* mode, respectively) in your configuration, you need to put the above commands after that occurrence.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been the bane of my existence since using zsh in vim mode.